# Kio estas "tinnitus" en Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, medicine

Glosbe donas "tinito", sed tiu vorto ne ekzistas en PIV.

Tekstaro havas nur unu trafon de artikolo de Monato.

Glosbe havas ankaŭ "orelbruo", sed neniu mencio en PIV aŭ Teksaro.

Bonvolu konsili.

Comment: Por fakaj terminoj, konsultinda estas [Esperantaj vortaroj en la reto](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperantaj_vortaroj_en_la_reto) : Terminaroj kaj fakaj leksikonoj

Comment: Tiu paĝo ne specife montras fakajn vortarojn.

Comment: Terminaroj kaj fakaj leksikonoj okupas proksimume trionon de la paĝo:
https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperantaj_vortaroj_en_la_reto#Terminaroj_kaj_fakaj_leksikonoj

Answer (score 3):

La Esperanta Vikipedio ankaŭ [nomas ĝin "tinito"](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinito) ([konstanta ligilo](https://eo.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Tinito&oldid=7312816)).
Sed la Esperanta Vikipedio ne ĉiam havas la plej kutiman esprimon por ne-ĉiutagaj aferoj.

Do kion uzas la fakuloj?

[Listigita de UEA estas kiel faka asocio por medicinistoj](https://uea.org/fakoj#Medicinistoj) la [Universala Medicina Esperanto-Asocio](https://uea.org/fakoj/UMEA) (UMEA).
En la [propra retejo de UMEA](http://umea.fontoj.net) estas [retpaĝo pri terminologio](http://umea.fontoj.net/terminologio/).
Tie oni povas legi:

> Kiel referenco UMEA ĉiam uzas
>
> „Angla-Esperanta Medicina Terminaro (AEMT)“ de [Yamazoe Saburoo](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamazoe_Saburoo) (ISBN 83-908748-1-4).
>
> Kelkaj ekzempleroj de tiu ĉi bonega terminaro estas ankoraŭ mendeblaj ĉe UMEA.

Tion mi ne havas.

Plie, oni povas legi:

> Ekzistas bone uzebla [terminaro nur kun kapvortoj en Esperanto](http://umea.fontoj.net/wp-content/uploads/medicina-terminaro.pdf) de [Josef Hradil](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josef_Hradil).

Tio estas elŝutebla per tiu ligilo kaj enhavas

> tinit/o, (L, A. timitus; F. tintement), cerba, orela ~o (orelzumo)

Do ankaŭ tie la uzata fakvorto estas "tinito".
Kaj ni lernis plian (eble ne-fakan) sinonimon: ["orelzumo"](http://www.simplavortaro.org/ser%C4%89o?s=orelzumo)

Por pli da certeco, oni devus verŝajne

- aŭ demandi UMEAn aŭ membroj ĝiaj
- aŭ demandi [la Lingvan Konsultejon](https://akademio-de-esperanto.org/konsultejo) de la Akademio de Esperanto
- aŭ akiri ekzempleron de AEMT kaj rigardi en ĝi

Comment: Pri « orelzumo », en PIV: « zumoj. Bruo de iu, io zumanta: orelaj zumoj (pro malsaneco) »

Answer (score 2):

Pro la *latineco* de la termino `tinnitus` kaj la apero en multaj liongvoj (des pli ke tio ankaŭ estas medicina termino) oni povas bone uzi **tinito**. Malgraŭ la ordinare evitinda ambigueco de **tin/it/o**. (Vidu la vikipediojn en diversaj lingvoj.)

Answer (score 1):

Mi ŝatas la solvon de la ĉina, kiu en la esperanta povus rezulti ekzemple la vorton *orelpepo* sed pli konvene estus por niaj lingvanoj uzi `orelsono`/`orelbruo` (ĉar la sono povas esti iu ajn).

Tio emfazas per simplaj ĉiutagaj elementoj ke la sono estas ena, kaj ne ekstera kaj pro tio ke oreloj ne produktas sonojn oni komprenas ke estas io nereala. Se temus pri artiko, aŭ mano aŭ osto, la kunmetaĵo kun *-sono* povus signifi faktan sonon. Se oni uzas `orelsono`/`orelbruo` oni povas mencii la kondiĉon ekzemple jene: *suferi je orelsonoj*.

Konsiderinda estas la prefikso [kvazaŭ](https://vortaro.net/#kvaza%C5%AD_kdc). Oni povus nomi la kondiĉon `kvazaŭaŭdo` kaj la sonojn `kvazaŭsonoj`. Sed por la persono kiu perceptas ilin, nek la aŭdo nek la sono estas kvazaŭa, do mi pensas ke `orelsono` povas taŭgi por ĉiuj kaj la aliaj ebloj povas utili por priskribo el la vidpunkto de kuracistoj ekzemple.

En klarigo uzeblus mis[percepto](https://vortaro.net/#percepto_kd), do oni povus diri *aŭda mispercepto* / *aŭdmispercepto* ([mis-](https://vortaro.net/#mis_kd) ĉi okaze estas uzata prefikse kun la signifo *ago erare farata*).